# I'm not able to assert body json properties

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I'm using Rest Assured to test my API. My client endpoint (`/client`) return a JSON like:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "nombre":"Juan Loquesea",
  "email":"juan@gmail.com",
  "idProvincia":7,
  "fechaRegistro":"06/04/2016 10:00:00"
}
```

And this is my test code:

```
public void test() {
    get("/client").then().assertThat()
           .statusCode(200)
           .body("id", equalTo(1));
}
```

But I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON expression:
Script1.groovy: 1: expecting EOF, found ':' @ line 1, column 31.
                            http://172.'20'.'20'.'20:8080'.id
                                 ^
```

What is happening?

Comment: looks like you do not receive your expected json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I had this code in my test class:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void init() {
  RestAssured.rootPath = "http:172.20.20.20:8080"
}
```

I have removed it and it is working now.